# Where is located state of mode of pull up/down resistor on Raspberry Pi 3 in operating system

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi3, gpio

I want to read mode (pull up/down/none). Is there place in the operating system, where is stored that information? I know how read from python but I have already running program using gpio and then I can't setup pin.

I tried to read from library 'lgpio' (in C++) by function 'lgGpioGetMode' or 'lgGpioGetLineInfo' but it was not working.

Regards

Comment: Who owns GPIO line that one can access to its property. If it's kernel, you can't get that in  user space via official interfaces AFAIU. But it rises an interesting question, i.e. if we can read (only) some properties of the line without requesting it or so.